# Does anyone here fork themself?

Tags: git, fork

I use git all the time for my solo missions but I tend to just work the `master`.

Should I try forking even if it's just me?

Comment: +1 Just because the title is so funny.

Comment: Yeah, usually in the left eye!

Comment: @ewall, yep. The best I've seen all day =) Though now I have an urge to repeat all the Blue Raja's jokes from [Mystery Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_Men)

Comment: Turns out I meant `branch`, but where's the fun in that.

Comment: Aren't you confusing forking with using branches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if it's just you I would suggest you to try the topic-branch workflow of git. First and foremost to get a feeling for it so you can apply it once you take part in bigger projects.

```
$ git branch usb_support
$ git checkout usb_support
.. hack hack hack ..
$ git checkout master
$ git merge usb_support
```

Obviously you can also switch to a different branches in between if you feel like working
on something else. Even if you are just on your own it happens that you start working on something only to later realize that it was a bad idea. In that case you can just throw away your topic branch and don't pollute the master branch. Of course if it's a project that nobody else will ever look at it does not matter that much even in the master branch. But then the gaining-experience-argument is still valid.

Comment: Sorry, my answer makes no sense because you were obviously talking about *forking* and not branching. Sorry. As for forking I do indeed so no need or use if we are talking about a one-man project that nobody else works one.. I guess personally i'd just tag the last commit before I go into a different direction and continue from there, no need for a fork

Answer (score 4):

**Forking** is about **cloning a repo on the remote side, because you don't have direct credential to push on the main common repo**.
That is why [GitHub introduced forking](http://help.github.com/forking/) (which is nothing else than a `git clone --bare` on the GitHub server side).

If you do have the right to push directly to a git repo, forking it (meaning establishing a second "common" repo on the remote side) is **not needed**.

Forking is not like a `git clone` you would do on the client side (i.e. on your workstation): there (on the local side) you can clone as many time as you want.

---

That is why [Chris Heilmann](http://fronteers.nl/congres/2010/speakers#christian-heilmann) will have [this slide](http://www.flickr.com/photos/codepo8/5018350616/) in his ["Reasons to be cheerful" presentation](http://fronteers.nl/congres/2010/sessions#reasons-to-be-cheerful) of [Fronteers 2010](http://fronteers.nl/congres/2010) (a non-profit trade organization of Dutch front-end developer), next October.

[image]
<sup>[CC license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/deed.en)</sup>

If you cannot directly contribute to a remote Git repo because you want to introduce drastic code, you can fork on the remote side, clone on the local side and pull/push at your heart's content.